# react native android manifest merging failed

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

my AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.package">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@networkSecurityConfig value=(@xml/react_native_config) from AndroidManifest.xml:9:7-67
        is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:9:7-67 value=(@xml/network_security_config).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-138 to override.
```

so whats wrong with my AndroidManifest.xml? I don't know why the build says i don't have the required lines in my xml file.. Maybe anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: the networkSecurityConfig is present in lines 7 and 9 so this is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

> tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"

is causing the manifest merger to be failed so remove it and rebuild your application again

Comment: Could you tell us more why that is working? On my linux, the same build runs without errors.

On my Mac, however, it gives this error.